# Simple Maths Riddle 3

Tags: riddle, mathematics, limerick

> My counterpart has committed multiple crimes;
>
> Square us and add: the result is not prime.
>
> You use me for a reason;
>
> I'm not liked by Cartesians;
>
> My converse is a measurement of time.

What am I?

Comment: Good riddle! Please make more of these :) $\qquad (+1)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My angle on this is you are:

> $\cos$

My counterpart has committed multiple crimes;

> Your counterpart is $\sin$ and this commits multiple crimes.

Square us and add: the result is not prime.

> Squaring and adding you and your counterpart,
>  $$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$$
>  which is not included as a prime number.

You use me for a reason;

> Cos sounds like cause - thanks to *Mea Culpa Nay*.

I'm not liked by Cartesians;

> You are used for angle based coordinates systems such as polar and not Cartesian.

My converse is a measurement of time.

> Converse meaning reciprocal gives the $\sec$ function.